# Mongo DB: What are the Performance issues in using $all

Tags: mongodb, performance

I am trying to search a list of values on a matching field in documents which is array of documents. Using $in makes it OR between the values I supply. Using $all seems to be more logical.

For eg:

Collection: Phrases 
sample doc:

```
{
  "locales": [
    {
      "name": "BPT",
      "internal_desc": "Entre 2 e 3 horas"
    },
    {
      "name": "JPN",
      "internal_desc": "2 ～ 3 時間"
    }
  ]
}
```

Query:

```
db.phrases.find({"locales.name":{"$all":["BPT", "JPN"]}})
```

But some posts suggesting $all is bad in terms of performance. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $and instead of $all will result in equivalent performance. The bottom line is that given what you are trying to accomplish using $all is your best bet (as far as my understanding goes). However, $all can be optimized by making the first element in the expression more selective. For example if you know that "BPT" shows up in 2% of documents and "JPN" shows up in 20% of documents then it makes sense to list "BPT" as the first element in the $all expression. This way mongo only needs to filter through fewer documents on each consecutive element in your $all expression. Im sure you've seen the documentation but here is a link nonetheless: [$all - mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)

Comment: Hi @Stuart, thank you for that explanation on giving the least occurring value as first element. That makes a lot of sense. And yes your understanding on my problem statement is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $and syntax, as shown in the query below;

```
db.phrases.find({$and : [
  {"locales.name" : "BPT"},
  {"locales.name" : "JPN"}
    ]
  });
```

You can get information about your query, to see what the db is doing when executing the query by using the explain command, as displayed below;

```
db.phrases.explain().find({$and : [
  {"locales.name" : "BPT"},
  {"locales.name" : "JPN"}
    ]
  });
```

Although, the explain command is more relevant to dbs where indexes are used, since it sort of gives you information about, which index was utilised by the db on the search.

Have a quick look into MongoDB indexes and explain() for further information.

I hope this helps.

Regards,

Nick.